# spring-boot Throttling with pagination

Tags: spring-boot, pagination, microservices, throttling, rate-limiting

I am trying to build a rest api in spring boot my rest api is offset/limit paging supported.
I want to apply Throttling in my rest api to apply rate limiting. Spring boot have multiple solution for Throttling, but i want Throttling to ignore in offset limit based request(my api contain four to five attributes in request params). when a user get all the data through pagination then count increase to one. Ignore if pagination not reached to last page

Comment: post what you have done so far.

Comment: i have written some code in service layer class to , but i want to remove that and do with spring provided classes